# How to place two content-sized HTML elements side by side?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have to generate the following layout for a web site with all elements sized by their content. I can not set the width of any element - maybe of the outermost container (0) if there is no other way.

The outermost container (0) is sized by other parts of the page layout. It contains several items (1) with equal structure. The container (1) contains some small content (2) - actually it is just a number; think of it as a chapter number. To the right of this number there is the container (3) with the actual content that consists of several parts (3) to (6). Not all of the content items (4) to (6) are always present; the present content items move to the top of the container (3) so that the first present content item is right of the number (2). The content items (4) to (6) may contain long texts that mus wrap around.

Finally this whole structure is nested three times - container (6) has the same structure as container  (1). In the deepest nesting level container (3) contains a possibly very wide table that must be horizontally scrollable.

```
 ___________________________________
|0 _______________________________  |
| |1 _____   ___________________  | |
| | |2    | |3 _______________  | | |
| | |_____| | |4              | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |  _______________  | | |
| |         | |5              | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |  _______________  | | |
| |         | |6              | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |___________________| | |
| |_______________________________| |
|                 .                 |
|                 .                 |
|                 .                 |
|  _______________________________  |
| |1 _____   ___________________  | |
| | |2    | |3 _______________  | | |
| | |_____| | |4              | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |  _______________  | | |
| |         | |5              | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |  _______________  | | |
| |         | |6              | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |               | | | |
| |         | |_______________| | | |
| |         |___________________| | |
| |_______________________________| |
|___________________________________|
```

So far I tried

- a layout using DIVs but failed to position (2) and (3) side by side
- a layout using DIVs and floating left (2) and (3) but either the content of (3) floats around (2) or (3) is moved below (2) if (3) becomes to wide
- a layout using DIVs and floating left (2) and floating right (3) but then the gap between (2) and (3) may become arbitrarily wide if the content of (3) is narrow
- a layout using nested tables with two columns - one for (2) and one for (3) - but failed to constrain the width of the tables to container (0). The very wide tables in the deepest nesting level just push all the cells and tables to the right.
- a layout based on DIVs with table display styles but the browser support was to poor so a quickly gave up this idea
- a layout using ordered list as described in this [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html) 12.4.1 but this will put the numbers inside (3). Further it is not guaranteed that my numbers are consecutive (but this could be fixed by explicitly setting the counters).

The final result should look like this.

```
1 Section Header

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur risus
  tortor, egestas id laoreet sit amet, sollicitudin nec ligula. Aliquam vitae
  justo lacus, non sagittis diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

  1.1 Question Header

      Orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent eu nisi vitae
      arcu cursus lobortis vitae vitae dui. Duis imperdiet varius molestie.
      Donec ut fermentum ligula.

      1.1.1 Nunc dictum, est non vestibulum adipiscing, lacus felis commodo
            orci, in commodo nibh ante ut dolor. Quisque posuere, lacus non
            rutrum sollicitudin, lectus sem commodo tellus, at hendrerit lacus
            neque mattis risus.
             ________________________________________________________________
            |           |           |           |           |           |    |
            | Header    | Header    | Header    | Header    | Header    | Hea|
            |___________|___________|___________|___________|___________|____|                
            |           |           |           |           |           |    |
            |           |           |           |           |           |    |
            |___________|___________|___________|___________|___________|____|
            |           |           |           |           |           |    |
            |           |           |           |           |           |    |
            |___________|___________|___________|___________|___________|____|
               ____________________________________________________________
            |<|____________________________________________________________|>|

      1.1.2 Nunc dictum, est non vestibulum adipiscing, lacus felis commodo
            orci, in commodo nibh ante ut dolor. Quisque posuere, lacus non
            rutrum sollicitudin, lectus sem commodo tellus, at hendrerit lacus
            neque mattis risus.

2 Section Header

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur risus
  tortor, egestas id laoreet sit amet, sollicitudin nec ligula. Aliquam vitae
  justo lacus, non sagittis diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

  2.1 Question Header

      Orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent eu nisi vitae
      arcu cursus lobortis vitae vitae dui. Duis imperdiet varius molestie.
      Donec ut fermentum ligula.
```

It is okay, that larger numbers push the content further to the right.

```
1 Section Caption
  1.1 Question Caption
10 Section Caption
   10.1 Question Caption
```

But aligning the content is also okay. This should be quite easy to achieve using one complex table instead of nested tables.

```
1  Section Caption
   1.1  Question Caption
10 Section Caption
   10.1 Question Caption
```

Then the numbers could also be right aligned but I think left aligned looks probably better - the lengths of the numbers don't vary that much.

```
 1 Section Caption
    1.1 Question Caption
10 Section Caption
   10.1 Question Caption
```

So the essence of the problem is to place the elements (2) and (3) side by side and having them sized by the content. Any ideas? Semantical correct solutions using nested ordered lists preferred over DIVs and DIVs slightly preferred over tables.

Comment: You should really see this extremely useful trick: Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I hope you are paypaling the person who answers this. Also, don't forget that inline-block exists.

Comment: @Sarfraz See my comment to nemophrost answer - positioning the elements (almost) always requires some assumptions about the size of elements. And this is exactly what I am trying to avoid; I want to size the elements by content only.

Comment: @meder I haven't really thought about inline-block yet. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick for you?

CSS

```
div {
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    min-height: 20px;
    min-width: 12px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div>
        <div style="position:absolute;"></div>
        <div style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <div style="position:absolute;"></div>
                <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div>
                        <div style="position:absolute;"></div>
                        <div style="margin-left:20px;">
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see what this does very quickly at http://jsfiddle.net/nemophrost/Zrabg/

Comment: This is the solution I am planning to use if I can not find a better solution. The problem is that you have to make assumptions about the  width of (2). I would like to avoid this because all the data comes from a database and users will have different display resolutions and font sizes - so sometimes there will be a large gap between (2) and (3) and sometimes (2) will overlap (3).

Comment: Like you mention, nested tables might end up being the way to go, and setting white-space:nowrap for the css of (2) to force it out to the right size.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is going to be to pick a good doctype.  HTML Strict is just awesome when used correctly.

Step 2 is going to be to either use a reset style sheet or explicitly set the div settings that way you get the last bit of browser compliance on the display.

Step 3 is that you are going to need a combination of Divs and tables.  You started down that path, but the tables weren't being constrained most likely due to doctype issues.  Try again.  This is probably the only way you will keep item 3 from falling below 2 if it exceeds the width alloted.

Comment: Does the DOCTYPE really influence the way elements are rendered? I always thought it will only change the set of valid elements while the rendering logic is specified in the CSS standard. A missing DOCTYPE might trigger switching to quirks mode, but I don't expect any rendering differences between different DOCTYPES provided only the common subset (x)HTML is used. Can you provide any references? A quick search did not bring up something relevant.

Comment: The problem with a combination of DIVs and tables is that DIVs are sized by the container while tables are sized by the content - therefore they don't nest very well. I read the relevant parts of the CSS specification and tend to believe that the sizing behavior I observed is (mostly) standard compliant.

Comment: @Daniel: The DOCTYPE declaration controls the rendering engine the browser users in order to display the page.  Each browser contains multiple engines and each of those have different layouts.  About the only one that is worth while (IMHO) is HTML 4.01 Strict.  Look at: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Comment: @Daniel: Additionally the DOCTYPE declaration controls things like padding and margin defaults.  Which, even with the same DOCTYPE browsers are still slightly inconsistent on a few features (like the IMG tag) which is why a reset style sheet is important to fix the last remaining items.

Comment: And here is another great site on the subject: http://www.ericmeyeroncss.com/bonus/render-mode.html  Yes, they talk about IE6 a lot, but it is more relevant than ever with the addition of chrome to the mix.